# Imaging.Imageformat which one is best fit in memory management

Tags: wpf, image, c#-4.0, memory-management

Which format among System.Drawing.Imaging.Imageformat is best options on what scenarios?

I am interested with respect to application memory consumption along with the quality of the image.

In my application I have images loading in memory where quality is not priority just the content in the image should be visible, Which Imageformat best fits here?

Comment: You can use the DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight on BitmapImage to get WPF to create a lower quality image (lower resolution)...don't use both, unless you know the aspect ratio.....then they takes up less memory when loaded...or you can use RenderTargetBitmap to create a smaller image. See here for example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/11/11/bigger-isn-t-always-better-how-to-resize-images-without-reloading-them-with-wpf.aspx

Comment: @colinsmith Thanks, I have already used decodepixelWidth, that is not saving much space though.RenderTargetBitmap, I will have a look.though thats really helpful link posted.

Comment: You will most certainly either display many small images or few large images at a time. So the solution to your problem is to reduce the PixelWidth/PixelHeight to the required minimum values and to only load those images that are actually shown on screen. Do not load all large images before they get actually shown on screen.

Comment: I thought the same initially but for a functionality with slider transformation(zoom) on the same UI screen,need to load all images first,it would be complex to calculate the no. of images that screen can fit at a time.Appreciate if you point me to some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory management is irrelevant - `ImageFormat` is used to control the format when saving an in-memory bitmap to an IO stream (e.g. a file on disk).

`Image`s in .NET are either `Bitmap`s or a vector `Metafile`. I'm fairly certain you're working with `Bitmap`, which means each instance you create will always occupy `Stride * Height * PixelFormat` bytes of memory.

While you could have the bytes of a well-compressed PNG or JPEG image in-memory (perhaps in a `MemoryStream` or `Byte[]` array), you won't be able to do anything with it (e.g. display it on-screen, modify the image's pixels, etc) until it's represented in-memory as a raster Bitmap, because that's what GDI+ (i.e. `System.Drawing.*`) needs.

(Yes, there are exceptions, such as loading a JFIF into memory and manipulating the DCT blocks (a la `jpegtran`), or using a graphics API such as Direct3D or OpenGL that has the ability to read compressed images directly into the graphics card's memory (but even then, textures would still be in-memory in a raster format).

Comment: I have tried with .png,jpeg,bmp,memorybmp all formats are consuming almost similar space in my RAM. Is there a way that I could reduce the memory space with reducing the image quality or so? To reduce the memory usage when displaying thousands of images on UI,what are the tricks to be used corresponding to bitmap usage?